# jQuery addClass appears not to be working in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, addclass, css-selectors

I have been trying to figure this out all afternoon with no luck. On this site I am working on (http://chezkoop.ca/united) we have a couple of areas (homepage columns one and two and the events page) which utilize the css pseudo selector `:nth-child()` to colour various rows.

Obviously, `nth-child()` does not work in Internet Explorer 8 and down (haven't looked at IE9 yet...) so I want to replicate this functionality with jQuery using the following (this being place inside `$(document).ready(function(){` ... `});`):

```
$(".post:nth-child(even)").addClass("latestpost-even");
$(".dbem_events_list li:nth-child(2n-1)").addClass("events-odd-row");
$("tr:nth-child(2n+1)").addClass("calendar-odd-row");
$("tr:nth-child(1)").addClass("calendar-first-row");
```

I have then defined those classes in my CSS like this (this is the first example only):

```
.post:nth-child(even), .latestpost-even {
background-color: #f5f4e8;
}
```

If I check the DOM in Firefox with Firebug these classes have been applied correctly (although unnecessarily, because I'm in Firefox). When viewing the page in Internet Explorer 8 or 7, the rows are not coloured (so presumably the classes are not being applied).

Been trying to figure this out all afternoon with no luck. I've had a search through the interwebs and haven't come up with anything. If anyone has any insight into this that would be fantastic.

Thanks

Adrian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of :

```
.post:nth-child(even), .latestpost-even {
   background-color: #f5f4e8;
}
```

try

```
.post:nth-child(even) {background-color: #f5f4e8;}

.latestpost-even {background-color: #f5f4e8;}
```

IE also has a little foible with those pseudos that it doesn't understand in that it will ignore the whole ruleset if it has a selector it doesn't understand

Comment: Thanks. Worked a charm. Definitely feel a little silly for not figuring this out!

Comment: You're Welcome, no worries it's just another IE foible, how are we supposed to remember them all ;)

Answer (score 3):

I can see in the Developer Tools in IE that the class gets added, both in IE7 and IE8 compatibility mode.

Perhaps IE is ignoring the line it doesn´t understand, so you could try:

```
.post:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f5f4e8;
}
.latestpost-even {
  background-color: #f5f4e8;
}
```

or, even better:

```
.latestpost-even, .post:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f5f4e8;
}
```

**Edit:** By the way, I was looking at `.events-odd-row` and not `.latestpost-even` but the same principle applies.

Comment: That makes so much sense. Feel like such an idiot for not trying this! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
$(".post:even")
```

or

```
$(".post").even()
```

(latter would require extended code -- see api comments...)

http://api.jquery.com/even-selector/

Answer (score 0):

Using Internet Explorer 7, I had the trouble of striping a table using jQuery :odd & :even addClass. Also, needed to change the background color of a selected row.

It would add the class to the row (checked using PageSpy, an inspector of dynamic DOM) but the effect would not be seen.

I needed to add the same class to each cell in the row for it to work.

Discovered jQuery's andSelf.

CSS

```
.odd{background-color:#fafafa;}

.even{background-color:#f4f4f4;}

.selected_row{background-color:#ff9999;}
```

Javascript

```
$('tbody#interest_list_body tr:odd').find('td').andSelf().addClass('odd');      
$('tbody#interest_list_body tr:even').find('td').andSelf().addClass('even');
```

and for the selected rows I used a toggle approach:

```
$('tbody#interest_list_body tr').toggle(  
   function(){  
    $('tbody#interest_list_body tr').find('td').andSelf().removeClass('selected_row');  
    if($(this).attr('id')){  
          $(this).find('td').andSelf().addClass('selected_row');  
    } // end if  
    }, // end fn  
   function(){  
          $(this).find('td').andSelf().removeClass('selected_row');  
    } // end fn  
);
```

Hope this helps someone