# IE8: Can't get last() or :last-child working in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, css-selectors

For the sake of an IE8 bug, I've been trying to add a `last` class to a few `<li>` with no luck.

Been reading about some problems here, found some solutions on Github, but nothing seems to bite on IE8 for me.

```
<ul>
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

And i tried:

`$('ul li:last-child').addClass('last1');`

`$('ul li').last().addClass('last2');`

Both work fine and show up in modern browsers, but IE gets nothing of that. Been clearing caches and reloading wildly.

Anything I'm perhaps not seeing or any other way to tackle this?

---

**Update 1**

Just saw that it works in Compatibility View.

---

**Update 2**

Managed to get it working somewhat. Used `.last()` and just ignored that IE8 dev tools doesn't show js added classes in the inspector although they're there.

The last piece of the problem though is that the change only becomes visible after I've moved the mouse over the li in question.

Tried the code below just in case it could trigger a redraw (which I suppose is what the mouse triggers?).

```
function lastli(){
    $('ul.button-group li').last().addClass('last');
    document.body.focus();
}

lastli();
```

Has anyone got an idea or should I ask this in a new question?

Comment: what version of jquery are you using?

Comment: code.jquery.com version of 1.9.1

Comment: Take a look at these posts http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655563/jquery-addclass-appears-not-to-be-working-in-internet-explorer

Comment: It should work. Anyway, try this: `$('ul').children('li').eq(this.length - 1)`

Comment: Just for info, from http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp: "Note: The :last-child selector is not supported in IE8 and earlier versions."

Comment: @Ricola3D that is for CSS.

Comment: Ricola, For your sake and mine, use w3schools only for their tutorials. Please do not use it as a refernce on SO or any other site

Comment: @Ricola3D jQuery still correctly interprets `:last-child` regardless of the browser.

Comment: The problem seems to be in some different place. start debugger in IE8 developer tool and re-run your program. and check where is the error happening actually.

Comment: Do you mind uploading more of your code? I just did quick test and last() does work on older browser. Here's the quick test i've written http://jsfiddle.net/bkSN5/show/      You can see my code at http://jsfiddle.net/bkSN5/

Comment: @Raver0124 Rewrote that to add a css class that set a red background as well, which worked. BUT, IE dev tools doesn't indicate that a class has been added, but the result still acts as if its there (red background). Le weird.

Comment: @Xavio AFAIK IE does not update the layout model(elements/CSS) on JS changes. You can see the difference but won't see the class added in the markup or the CSS change for the element if you inspect it in IE dev tools.

Comment: RE: IE not showing updates in devtools: If I recall correctly, there's a refresh button in there. You will need to pick your way through the DOM again though, as it collapses any element you'd clicked open in the inspector.